# ng-options throws object Object as a result

Tags: angularjs

I´m trying to create a drop down list, however, the results shown once the user clicks on the text box are:

```
Seleccione Impuestos de Compra
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

this is my `<DIV>`:

```
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                           <label>
                               Impuestos de J5
                           </label>
                           <select ng-options="item for item in impuestos_compra" ng-model="articulo.impuestos_compra"
                                    name="impuestos_compra" class="form-control input-lg" required>
                               <option value="">Seleccione impuesto de compra</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
```

And here is my `<SCRIPT>`:

```
$scope.articulo.impuestos_compra = $scope.articulo.impuestos_compra.map( function ( impCompra ){
            console.log('dd' , impCompra);
            return impCompra.nombre;
        });
```

Can somebody tell me what am'I doing wrong and what I'm missing? I'm totally new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.articulo={
impuestos_compra:[1,2,3,4,5]
}; 


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<label>Impuestos de J5</label>
<select  ng-model="slectedItem" name="impuestos_compra" class="form-control input-lg" ng-options="item for item in articulo.impuestos_compra" required ng-change="selectChange()">
<option value="">Seleccione impuesto de compra</option>

</select>
<p>{{slectedItem}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```